Does pruning my pine tree rectangularly strengthen roots, and could they reach my house?
A gardener told me that he can prune my pine tree. I was advised that if the tree is pruned into a rectangular shape (to encourage vertical growth), the roots will grow stronger compared to pruning it into an umbrella shape. Is this true ?
Given the space I have, I'm concerned that the roots might expand and reach the house. Should I be worried about this?

Pine tree

Hi, welcome to the site. Who told you this?

Did you mean rectangular or did you mean conical?

Thank you for your comment, @davidgo ! Sorry, I meant conical. What did you mean by "topping the tree" ? And also, what do you mean by "that tree does not appear to have a central leader" ?

I am not an expert here, but - A leader is the main branch. The pine trees I'm familiar with have a single  big trunk in the center that have branches coming off. This is the leader. Cutting this main vertical branch is topping the tree (ie cutting the top of the tree). AFAIK pine trees diverged from other types of trees very early on and are a little different to  most other trees.

(Your pine tree does not look "right" to me as there is no clear central leader - so I am guessing the main vertical uprights should each be treated as a leader.)

Thank you @davidgo for your input.

I have seen no such research. Pines have tap roots. Which means they mainly go downwards. If the soil is too hard or compacted or stony, this can hamper this process.  That is, pruning will not make the roots spread.
You can get it pruned without this fear. But long term, I  would worry about branches breaking off or even the whole tree getting uprooted in high winds. I would suggest that this is not a good location for such a large tree.

Apologies, but I'm not sure i agree with this answer.  If by "Rectangular" the OP meant "conical", which I think is likely, topping a pine tree (which would make it a more umbrella shape) will likely have a negative impact on the trees health.   On the other hand, that tree does not appear to have a central leader and the tree which would be worrying to me.

Its not a forestry tree.  And in my experience the pines are very hardy wrt to pruning.  I had an acre of them as a forestry block.  Besides the main part of the answer is that pruning wont make the roots spread
